# C++ OpenCL automatic kernel calling

Tags: c++, opencl

I am facing a problem:

i am writing a raytracer in opencl, and i want to keep my code clean and simple, so i want to crate a runKernel() function, that will take in list of arguments, kernel function name and will return list of arguments. I want the function to create buffers for all the arguments and write them to device and other things like that.

I started writing this function, and i ran to problem really fast: How do i return unspecified amount of unspecified types of arguments?

```
Object[] runKernel(string functionName, Object[] arguments)
{
 return null;
}
```

Obviously there is not any "Object" class in c++, so what do I put there? And please tell me if I'm taking totally wrong approach to this.

Comment: Don't pass arrays, use a container like `std::vector` instead.

Comment: what do i pass to vector then?

Comment: You build your vector first, and then pass it to or from your function.

Comment: std::vector<WHAT HERE?> runKernel(string functionName, std::vector<THIS NEEDS SOMETHING>)

Comment: As a side note, arrays as you have in your sample don't have a concept of 'length' like they do in managed languages. So by passing an array, you're passing a set of items with indeterminate size. In fact, your signature might as well just be passing `Object*` (pointer to `Object`) because that's about the same amount of information as is being passed. Hence, you have to use a container to handle something like this. Generally for things like this its better to pass by constant reference (`runKernel (..., const vector<Object>& arguments`), which passes the *same* object, rather than a copy.

Comment: The question here is, you need to have these parameters known at compile time? Or run time? Do you plan to make a code that will be compiled with the code that consumes it? Or will be just linked? You are facing a C versatile library generation problem, rather than OpenCL related problem. If the code will be used at compile time, maybe you can somehow create a template that will do the trick (or even a macro).

Comment: In other words, you may consider getting stronger at core C++ before attempting this. Everything you've described so far is a C++ issue, not an OpenCL problem.

Comment: You might look into the cl.hpp wrapper which has some functions which can wrap the clSetKernelArg and clEnqueueNDRangeKernel calls with a single function call.

Comment: Though, good advices are already given, my advice is don't mix up OpenCL essences. Kernel can't be run itself as method of class or something like this. It's bound to command queue. Same to kernel arguments - allocation in kernel call time is poor design in my opinion and it will lead to difficulties in future. I think, it's better to use C++ wrapper from Khronos or other wrappers.